# Eclipse RCP Product File - how to handle multiple platforms with platform specific dependencies

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, equinox

I have an Eclipse RCP application, whose `.product` file contains references to native SWT plugins.

```
   <plugins>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
   </plugins>
```

However, on other platforms (e.g. Mac) those plugins cannot be resolved. If you use the Mac version of that plugin (e.g. `org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64`) everything works fine.

Is there some way I specify different plugins for different environments, or a more generic plugin?

I appreciate that when it comes to deploying multi-platform RCP products, things get complex - but at the moment I'm just trying to make it as simple as possible for developers on multiple platforms to get up and running with the application, rather than end users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61129434) provided by greg-449, I noticed that you can have multiple contradicting plugins without issue - i.e. both Windows & Mac plugins can be specified and at runtime Eclipse will use whatever it can find.

This means that by specifying both plugins, despite one always being displayed as an error (as it's unresolvable on that platform), it works fine.

Comment: You can mark those plugins as optional then you don't get an error.

Comment: @Robert do you have an example of the syntax? I can't see anything online about this?

Comment: Not sure if the effect is the same but I have a custom Eclipse plugin that imports platform specific parts of Eclipse via their bundle name in MANIFEST.MF. For bundles you can make the resolution optional. This automatically happens if you add a "Required plugin" on the "Dependencies" tab for an Eclipse Plugin project.

Answer (score 1):

Use a feature based product file rather than plug-in based.

The feature.xml file defining a feature can specify the OS / GUI / architecture.

This is what the standard Eclipse `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` feature.xml has for the SWT plug-in / fragments:

```xml
<plugin
      id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64"
      os="macosx"
      ws="cocoa"
      arch="x86_64"
      download-size="40"
      install-size="88"
      version="1.1.1100.v20190907-0426"
      fragment="true"/>

<plugin
      id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.ppc64le"
      os="linux"
      ws="gtk"
      arch="ppc64le"
      download-size="76"
      install-size="253"
      version="1.1.1100.v20190907-0426"
      fragment="true"/>

<plugin
      id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64"
      os="linux"
      ws="gtk"
      arch="x86_64"
      download-size="69"
      install-size="166"
      version="1.1.1100.v20190907-0426"
      fragment="true"/>

<plugin
      id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64"
      os="win32"
      ws="win32"
      arch="x86_64"
      download-size="80"
      install-size="161"
      version="1.1.1100.v20190907-0426"
      fragment="true"/>

<plugin
      id="org.eclipse.swt"
      download-size="16"
      install-size="32"
      version="3.114.0.v20200304-0601"
      unpack="false"/>
```